# adb server is out of date. killing... cannot bind 'tcp:5037' ADB server didn't ACK * failed to start daemon * error:

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, genymotion

I am using genymotion in Linux machine. I used react native to start the project file when it's complete I get an error of device not found but the app is installed in the virtual device of genymotion.Even after ADB kill and start I don't get, I get an error as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Android Studio are you using??? It seams that the version of the ADB is needing an update.

Comment: Its 1.0.32 newest version !!

Comment: Referency this link http://www.programering.com/a/MTNyUDMwATA.html
Try to do this:

1º In terminal of your OS `adb nodaemon server`  
( You'll probably see the error you mentioned)

2º And then do : 

 - Windows - `netstat -ano | findstr "5037"` 
or
 - Linux - `netstat -pan | grep 5037`

(That will show the app that's using your port)

3º And then  kill the process that appear 
 

 - Windows is somethin' like this `taskkill /pid [signal]`
 - 
Linux somethin' like this `kill [signal] PID`

Kill all the adb process.

Restart your IDE, and should work. :)

Best regards